# Parse Password Reset Error in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, password-recovery

I am using the code below for password reset as declared in parse documentation: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-resetting-passwords
However I get the error: *"cannot invoke "requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground" with an argument of type (string (bool!,nserror!)->Void)*

The code I am using is:

```
  var emailVar = emailField.text
    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(emailVar) { (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Password recovery e-mail sent", message: "Please check your e-mail inbox for recovery", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }else {

            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Could not found your e-mail", message: "There is no such e-mail in our database", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In new parse api error changed to an `optional` value, using like that :

```
PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(emailVar) {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

}
```